# MS Access - Multiple iif

Tags: ms-access, iif

I'm trying to put an if i have in excel to access.
But I have a big condition, in total its 7 if's, but when I try to transpose it to access, the field on the design view, doesn't accept all the text I try to write (its to big).

Basically I want to say what kind of TV package the client the technician is installing, and if installed a TV box too. But there are several conditions.

the conditions i have are :

```
1- all conditions: [Order]= connect 
2- [Item]= "MIX" **= "MIX"** 
3- [Item]= "OTHER" **= "OTHER"**   
4- [Item] = "TV BOX" and [order]= connect and [Item]= "X Selection", or [Item]= 
"Y Selection" **= "Selection with Box"**  
5- [Item] = "TV BOX" and [order]= connect and [Item]= "XPTO 1" and [Item]= "XPTO 2" or [Item]= "DIGITAL 1" or [Item]= "DIGITAL 2" and [Type]= "MASS BUSINESS" **= "MASS BUSINESS with box"**  
6- [Item] = "TV BOX" and [order]= connect **= "PACKAGE WHATEVER with box"**
7- [PreviousPackage]  last 9 words a = "with box" will add "with box" in the end - **"PACKAGE WHATEVER with box"** 
8- else will be "PACKAGE WHATEVER without box"
```

I have a query table that will say if the technician installed a TV BOX its call "with box installed"

How can i do this big the rest of the conditions in access? Can you give me a clue?

Comment: Where are you trying to do this calc? To construct a field in a query? Or filter criteria for a query? Apply filter to form or report, not query. Review http://www.allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: But i dont want to filter anything, i just want to have a new column that tells me what is the new tv package the client as and if as a tv box or dont. But with the conditions above

Comment: Well, condition 4 and 5 make no sense. No record could have all 3 values in [Item] field and therefore would never match. Even if I could make sense of your criteria, the expression looks like it would exceed 255 character limit. Probably need a custom function.

Comment: You right, the 4 or 5 was an "or" in the [item], and not "and" my bad writhing, i will edit. What do you mean costum function? VBA?

Comment: Yes, VBA in a general module and the function could be called from query or textbox.